# Ubuntu 16.04 Systemd not possible to use systemctl

Tags: linux, ubuntu, systemd, ubuntu-16.04, systemctl

I have a Ubuntu 16.04 server, since the last restart, 
systemctl doesn't work anymore.

For example if I want to start the nginx, I get the following error:

```
root@SERVER:/# systemctl start nginx
Failed to start nginx.service: Unknown unit: nginx.service
```

The same result for every other service.
Just systemctl gives the following result:

```
root@SERVER:/# systemctl
Failed to list units: No such method 'ListUnitsFiltered'
```

Thanks

---

```
apt autoremove
Start-Date: 2016-11-12  20:37:29
Commandline: apt autoremove
Remove: linux-image-4.4.0-38-generic:amd64 (4.4.0-38.57), libsnappy1v5:amd64 (1.1.3-2), libboost-program-options1.58.0:amd64 (1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1), linux-image-4.4.0-36-generic:amd64 (4.4.0-36.55), libboost-filesystem1.58.0:amd64 (1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1), libv8-3.14.5:amd64 (3.14.5.8-5ubuntu2), linux-headers-4.4.0-36-generic:amd64 (4.4.0-36.55), libboost-thread1.58.0:amd64 (1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1), linux-headers-4.4.0-34-generic:amd64 (4.4.0-34.53), linux-headers-4.4.0-38-generic:amd64 (4.4.0-38.57), libboost-system1.58.0:amd64 (1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1), linux-image-4.4.0-22-generic:amd64 (4.4.0-22.40), linux-image-4.4.0-42-generic:amd64 (4.4.0-42.62), libtcmalloc-minimal4:amd64 (2.4-0ubuntu5), linux-headers-4.4.0-22:amd64 (4.4.0-22.40), linux-headers-4.4.0-34:amd64 (4.4.0-34.53), linux-headers-4.4.0-36:amd64 (4.4.0-36.55), linux-headers-4.4.0-38:amd64 (4.4.0-38.57), linux-headers-4.4.0-42:amd64 (4.4.0-42.62), linux-headers-4.4.0-22-generic:amd64 (4.4.0-22.40), libgoogle-perftools4:amd64 (2.4-0ubuntu5), linux-headers-4.4.0-42-generic:amd64 (4.4.0-42.62), libunwind8:amd64 (1.1-4.1), libpcrecpp0v5:amd64 (2:8.38-3.1), libyaml-cpp0.5v5:amd64 (0.5.2-3), linux-image-4.4.0-34-generic:amd64 (4.4.0-34.53)
End-Date: 2016-11-12  20:41:18
```

---

```
root@SERVER:/home# dpkg --list | grep systemd
ii  libpam-systemd:amd64             229-4ubuntu12                     amd64        system and service manager - PAM module
ii  libsystemd0:amd64                229-4ubuntu12                     amd64        systemd utility library
ii  python3-systemd                  231-2build1                       amd64        Python 3 bindings for systemd
ii  systemd                          229-4ubuntu12                     amd64        system and service manager
ii  systemd-shim                     9-1bzr4ubuntu1                    amd64        shim for systemd
```

Comment: `apt-get autoremove` looks OK so far. I have read that this error can occur when different library versions of `systemd` are installed. You you also check that with `dpkg --list | grep systemd` and add the output to your question.

Comment: @Thomas I appended the ouput at the end of the question

Comment: Are all your partitions properly mounted (particularly if you have a separate one for `/etc` and/or `/usr`)? Also, what does `find / -name "*.service"` yield?